# How to error handle if the element of the 2d list is not within range

Tags: python, list, function, error-handling

I am trying to error handle the input of the doughnuts_gone. The user should enter the element position of the list. eg if they wanted to delete the order of the 6 cream doughnuts for $18, then you should enter the position of the list; first list so position 0, and then the list element position in the 2d list is removed. The problem with my program is I do not know how to write the elif stament for if the number entered is not within the range of the elements available in the list:

```
elif i != total_order[i]:
```

Simplified program:

```
def check_valid(prompt):
        while True:
            try:
                i = int(input(prompt))
                if i == '':
                    print("You must enter a value for the doughnut item you would like to change.")
                    print()
                elif i != total_order[i]:
                    print("Invalid")
                else:
                    break
            except:
                break
        return i

total_order = [['Cream',6,18], ['Cookies',5,20], ['Jam',6,16]]

for i in range(len(total_order)):
    print("{}     {} {} Doughnuts = ${:.2f}".format(i, total_order[i][1],total_order[i][0],total_order[i][2]))
doughnuts_gone = check_valid("Enter the number associated with the doughnut order you would like to remove? ")
```

Thank you! I hope this makes sense! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You checked the `i` variable as a string (`if i == '':`) but it is casted to integer in the previous line (`i = int(input(prompt))`). You should check the length of your list instead of this line: `elif i != total_order[i]:`. your script didn't work due to this issues. I have written a working code and I have tested it. Please see below my code/test.

Furthermore your van improve your code (Eg.: Check if the input can be casting to integer or not.).

**Code:**

```
def check_valid(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            i = input(prompt)
            if not i:
                print("You must enter a value for the doughnut item you would like to change.")
                print()
            elif int(i) > len(total_order)-1:
                print("Invalid")
            else:
                break
        except:
            break
    return int(i)


total_order = [['Cream', 6, 18], ['Cookies', 5, 20], ['Jam', 6, 16]]

for i in range(len(total_order)):
    print("{}     {} {} Doughnuts = ${:.2f}".format(i, total_order[i][1], total_order[i][0],
                                                    total_order[i][2]))
doughnuts_gone = check_valid(
    "Enter the number associated with the doughnut order you would like to remove? ")
print("Valid value! Selected one: {}".format(total_order[doughnuts_gone]))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
0     6 Cream Doughnuts = $18.00
1     5 Cookies Doughnuts = $20.00
2     6 Jam Doughnuts = $16.00
Enter the number associated with the doughnut order you would like to remove? 3
Invalid
Enter the number associated with the doughnut order you would like to remove? 
You must enter a value for the doughnut item you would like to change.

Enter the number associated with the doughnut order you would like to remove? 0
Valid value! Selected one: ['Cream', 6, 18]
```